# Making a button not appear if an aria-label appears within the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Within this else statement, I'm trying to say that if there is an `aria-label` whose value is "Comment" within the uCW div, don't add the button. Otherwise, add the button. Nothing is appearing.

```
        else {
            if ($(uCW).find([aria-label=="Comment"]))
                {rollback}
            else
                {more.before(button);}
            }
```

This is the `aria-label` I'm trying to NOT add buttons to (it's inside uCW and within a lot of divs)

```
<div class="l9j0dhe7 ecm0bbzt hv4rvrfc qt6c0cv9 dati1w0a lzcic4wl btwxx1t3 j83agx80" aria-label="Comment" role="article" tabindex="-1">
```

Comment: Attributes are strings. I'll add an answer to reflect what you should be writing.

Comment: You really should also post minimum HTML/JS/CSS code so we can recreate the issue in a snippet. I'm not sure what behavior you're after essentially.

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the attribute using a `string`. Like this `$("[meta-tag='value']");`

I'll amend my answer when you post code that will be more specific. :)

```js
const aria = $("[aria-label='Comment']");

console.log(aria);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="l9j0dhe7 ecm0bbzt hv4rvrfc qt6c0cv9 dati1w0a lzcic4wl btwxx1t3 j83agx80" aria-label="Comment" role="article" tabindex="-1">
</div>

<div class="not"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using == instead the = on a selector. Also you must add quotes in your find selectors. You can do the following in Jquery:

```
$('.your-div').find('[aria-label="Comment"]');
```

Then, you can check if they were found using:

```
if ($('.your-div').find('[aria-label="Comment"]').length > 0) {
  // aria label = Comment found
} else {
  // ...
};
```

If you assign this condition to a const, your code can be more semantic:

```
const ariaLabelComment = $('.your-div').find('[aria-label="Comment"]').length > 0;

if (ariaLabelComment) {
  // aria label = Comment found
} else {
  // ...
};
```

In Pure javasript

```js
const uCW = document.querySelector('.your-ucw-div-selector');

const ariaLabelComment = uCw.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Comment"]').length > 0;

if (ariaLabelComment) {
  // found
} else {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check inside uCW has label comment as

```
var exist = $(".uCW [aria-label='Comment']").length;
    if( exist == 0 )
    {
      $(".uCW").append("<button>Test</button>");
    }
```

```js
var exist = $(".uCW [aria-label='Comment']").length;
if( exist == 0 )
{
  $(".uCW").append("<button>Test</button>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uCW">
<div class="l9j0dhe7 ecm0bbzt hv4rvrfc qt6c0cv9 dati1w0a lzcic4wl btwxx1t3 j83agx80" aria-label="Comment" role="article" tabindex="-1">
</div>
```